# Is it possible to get the best ME3 ending without Live Gold membership?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer, mass-effect-infiltrator

I'm playing with XBox360, no XBox Live Gold membership. 2nd-hand game, but there was free download of EA online pass, so I just redeemed that (but of course can't play multiplayer without Gold), and have the account successfully linked at [N7 HQ](http://social.bioware.com/n7hq/).

In the game, I am currently at the point just before the end game phase starting with the assault on Cerberus space station and the Illusive Man, with total military strength ~5600, and the default readiness 50%.

While carefully avoiding spoilers, I've managed to read that I need effective military strength 5000 to get the best ending, so I'm like half the way there, and not many uncompleted quests.

**Questions**, considering current date and details above, in order of importance:

- *Is the 5000 point requirement true?* (And yes, I realize it doesn't buy me much, but I consider it a bit like missing last page of a book I've been reading since ME1 came out...)
- *Is it possible to reach the best ending in single player only?* Briefly, how? Like, is there some part of the game I can grind to get it?
- Based on my own research, it seems I could buy Mass Effect: Infiltrator for Android, and get galactic readiness up by that. Now the question is, will it work in practice? That is, can I really get enough military strength and readiness rating, considering where I am now? Can I do it without in-app purchases on top of the game price itself?
- If I get a Live Gold pass, can I actually play the online multi-player still, find other players available for play with a newbie, when it's been so long since the game was released? How much online play time would it require to get to my goal?

Comment: And I'd like to emphasize, that this question is in the context of the time it's being asked. There are older questions in Related section, but I couldn't really find a relevant, clear answer there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can - in the Extended Cut free DLC which updates ("fixes") the endings, the required EMS readiness was lowered to 3100 from 4000 ([SPOILERS - source - Extended Cut info](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3:_Extended_Cut)) and it is certanly possible to achieve the 6100 military strength points required for best endings with 50% readiness penalty just by playing ME3 singleplayer without any multiplayer or mobile game addons.

Just make sure you grab the free DLC from Xbox Live before playing.

Comment: Sounds good! I actually found and downloaded that already. But a question based on your "before playing", does it apply to a game already in progress?

Comment: I had finished the game before this DLC was released. When I downloaded it and loaded the save just before the Cerberus assault, the changes in the DLC were taken into account on my game. So I think it should work for your game as well.

Comment: @Adeese Thanks for the info. So I guess I'll go exploring a bit more and aim for that 2x3100 military strength. I hope I haven't missed anything, though buying some DLC missions for extra assets doesn't actually sound that bad.

Comment: @hyde - Most of the DLC for this game is actually really good (ESPECIALLY Citadel, if you played 1 and 2) so it's worth the investment IMO.

Comment: If I recall correctly I managed to get enough readiness even in vanilla ME3 without playing multiplayer - but I REALLY had to do every single one of side quests correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

I kind of have to give you a spoiler if you want to know how to get the best ending, so unless you want to figure it out for yourself, don't read any further.

Besides making sure that your EMS is at 3100, you HAVE to choose the ***Destroy*** ending, or you will not get the ***best*** ending.

EMS = 3100
Choice = Destroy

Answer (score 0):

I got the singularity ending on PS3 trilogy set after beating the first two and getting all the assests. I could without any dlc´s for any of them and only 50% readiness.

But I did keep all my crew alive in me2 and used all good choices to save all my alliances and sa e the geth.